# Read ArrayList from file. Print words that appear only ONCE

Tags: java, arraylist

Newbie to coding and Java, please be kind :)

I'm working on a project for school and I'm trying to iterate over an `ArrayList` that I read in from a text file.

I read the file in using a Scanner into an `ArrayList` and then sort the `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort()` with the hopes that I can check each element with the next one. If the element is the same as the next one, ignore and continue but if the element is not *duplicated* in the `ArrayList`, then add it to a new `ArrayList`.

So, when reading in a text file that has these words:

```
this this is a a sentence sentence that does not not make sense a sentence not sentence not really really why not this a sentence not sentence a this really why
```

the new `ArrayList` should be

`is that does make sense`

because those words only appear once.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {   
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> uniqueArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> tempArrList   = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
        tempArrList.add(fileIn.next());
        Collections.sort(tempArrList);            
    }           

    for (String s : tempArrList) {
        if(!uniqueArrList.contains(s))
            uniqueArrList.add(s);

            else if (uniqueArrList.contains(s))
                uniqueArrList.remove(s);

            Collections.sort(uniqueArrList);  
           System.out.println(uniqueArrList);
    }
```

This is what I have so far but I keep ending up with this `[a, does, is, make, really, sense, that]`

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: So many sorts? :). Can you move your unique sort after the loop?

Comment: Your logic error when you call uniqueArrList.remove(s);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is not correct, because it keeps adding and removing items from `uniqueArrList`. Hence, it finds words that appear an odd number of times, and it does not care for the list to be sorted.

You can sort the list once (move `sort` out of the loop) and then use a very simple strategy:

- Walk the list using an integer index
- Check the word at the current index against the word at the next index
- If words are different, print the current word, and advance index by one
- If words are the same, walk the list forward until you see a different word, and use the location of that word as the next value for the loop index.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
    list.add(fileIn.next());
}           
Collections.sort(list);
int pos = 0;
while (pos != list.size()) {
    int next = pos+1;
    while (next != list.size() && list.get(pos).equals(list.get(next))) {
        next++;
    }
    if (next == pos+1) {
        System.out.println(list.get(pos));
    }
    pos = next;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/FOaJAT)

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to maintain a hashmap of words to counts as you parse the file.  Then, iterate that map at the end to obtain the words which only appeared once:

```
Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> uniqueArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
    String word = fileIn.next():
    Integer cnt = map.get(word);
    map.put(word, cnt == null ? 1 : cnt.intValue() + 1);
}

// now iterate over all words in the map, adding unique words to a separate list
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
        uniqueArrList.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You current approach is close, you should be sorting once after you add all the words. Then you need to keep an index to the `List` so you can test if equal elements are adjacent. Something like,

```
List<String> uniqueArrList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> tempArrList = new ArrayList<>();

while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
    tempArrList.add(fileIn.next());
}
Collections.sort(tempArrList);

for (int i = 1; i < tempArrList.size(); i++) {
    String s = tempArrList.get(i - 1);
    if (s.equals(tempArrList.get(i))) {
        // skip all equal and adjacent values
        while (s.equals(tempArrList.get(i)) && i + 1 < tempArrList.size()) {
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        uniqueArrList.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println(uniqueArrList);
```

Comment: I really like this approach but the final ArrayList is missing the last word. Do you know why?

Comment: @Jenny I get `[does, is, make, sense, that]` - which word is missing?

Comment: I was testing with a different file, sorry. This works for me now. Thank you, Elliott :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a Set or a HashSet since you forget to control the elements' repetition. However, if you have to use lists, there is no need to sort the elements. Just iterate twice over the words and there you go

```
List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        boolean hasDuplicate = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (words.get(i).equals(words.get(j))){
                    hasDuplicate = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!hasDuplicate) {
            uniqueWords.add(words.get(i))
        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach is not efficient and major improvements can be done but I hope it helps you a bit

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and answers my question :)  Thanks, Gerardo!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic error when you call

```
else if (uniqueArrList.contains(s))
      uniqueArrList.remove(s);
```

Use One Array:

```
            Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
            ArrayList<String> tempArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
                tempArrList.add(fileIn.next());
            }

            Collections.sort(tempArrList);
            System.out.println(tempArrList);

            if (tempArrList.size() > 1) {
                for (int i = tempArrList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    String item = tempArrList.remove(i);
                    if (tempArrList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(item))) {
                        if (i > tempArrList.size()) {
                            i = tempArrList.size();
                        }
                    } else {
                        tempArrList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(tempArrList);
```

I hope it can help you! Please feedback if it helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you know how to do it with only ONE ArrayList? :)

Comment: I has edit use ONE ArrayList. Please feedback if it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness only, this question is a no brainer with Java 8 Streams, using the distinct() intermediate operation:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {    
    final Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    final List<String> tempArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
        tempArrList.add(fileIn.next());
    }

    final List<String> uniqueArrList = tempArrList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(uniqueArrList);
}
```

This code prints (for the provided input):

[this, is, a, sentence, that, does, not, make, sense, really, why]

If we want all the words sorted, simply adding sorted() to the stream pipeline does the trick:

```
tempArrList.stream().sorted().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and we obtain a sorted (and pretty) output:

[a, does, is, make, not, really, sense, sentence, that, this, why]